# Error at launch of aps-iot-extensions-demo: The file extension loaded into the viewer is not supported

Tags: autodesk-forge

When launching the [aps-iot-extensions-demo](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo), I get the following error:

> The file extension loaded into the viewer is not supported

[Image showing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giMbM.png)

I have a 2022 revit model (.rvt), with URN and GUID.

Same problem when using the rac_basic_sample_project.rvt

Comment: Could you share the contents of your config files with me? It looks like related to your URN.

Comment: Hi @eason-kang . Here is my `config.js` : [config.js Gist](https://gist.github.com/salahelfarissi/784796c339ea39ec917f919db6f203fc)

Comment: Hi @salahelfarissi, Thanks, it looks fine. If so, let's do some experiments. I shared some code snippets in your gist. Please have a try.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please test the model with a simple viewer to check if the model is viewable. For example, https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/